# Ask root for password when using su command

Tags: ubuntu, password, root, su

I'm trying to edit `/etc/sudoers` via `visudo`, but I don't know how to change the root rights.

I want root to be prompted for the user1's password, when he tries to use `su user1`.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, and it doesn't make sense. Why do you want root to be prompted for user1's password? It doesn't actually protect user1's account from root when root doesn't know the password.

Comment: Maybe this is useless. This is just a question from a lab in my university. I guess this is possible, because you can indicate a user the the commands he can use without password. 
For instance : gatoatigrado ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/set-slow-cpufreq

Comment: Ah, I see. So you could probably exclude su from the ALL tag to make this work.

Comment: sudo and su are 2 completely different commands. Nothing you do to /etc/sudoers will have any impact on how the su command behaves.

Comment: Well, I added a new line to the the /etc/sudoers:
root  ALL = (ALL:ALL) PASSWD:/usr/bin/su.
Unfortunately still not working:(

Comment: Cry Havok, but will have impact on how root acces the su, I guess.

Comment: Maybe the pam config could do it. I have `/etc/pam.d/su` on my system.

Comment: Should be this. I commented the first line : auth sificient pam_root.so , but doesn't work.

Comment: That's it! Thanks it was commenting the line that says
"auth suficient pam_root.so"

ans adding the "auth  required     pam_unix.so".
I don't know what exactlly the last command do, but was compulsory to get this work properly.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: @ice_mint You should answer the question with the details. Also, possibly make the question more generic so that it's more useful.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not really a good idea, but it IS possible. As somebody here pointed out, you can't prevent root from being the computer's god, but you can modify the "su" program to ask for passwords. It can prevent root from re-logging to other accounts unless he compiles his own version of su and uses it.

First, you'll need a compiler to be able to re-build su. As a root, perform:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Then, download and prepare the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/):

```
ftp://ftp.task.gda.pl/pub/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.13.tar.gz
tar xvf coreutils-8.20.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.20
./configure
```

Now access the **src** directory and locate the **su.c** file. In line 223, you'll find:

```
if (getuid () == 0 || !correct || correct[0] == '\0')
```

Change it to:

```
if (!correct || correct[0] == '\0')
```

Now, back in the **coreutils-8.20** directory, run make. Compilation might take long time. Once it's done, overwrite the current su binary with the new one:

```
cp src/su `which su`
```

And again - you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1. root never needs a password to do anything.  root is an all powerful user.  root=superuser=administrator=chucknorris
2. as @Cry Havok pointed out /etc/sudoers has nothing to do with `su`, only `sudo`

SIDENOTE: running `su - <user>` as a regular user (non-root/unprivileged)  will always ask for a password.

Comment: Not true.  Chucknorris once removed the root account from all Unix machines in the world.  He just added it back a few seconds later because he decided to be benevolent.

Answer (score 4):

Root can become any user without requiring any authentication. Even if the `su` command was configured to prompt for a password, root could use some other program to issue the underlying system call. The `su` command is normally configured not to require a password because it's useless for security, and a lot of non-interactive scripts rely on that to perform tasks as a less privileged user.

On Ubuntu (and many other systems that use [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules)), the absence of a password prompt when root runs `su` is implemented by the following line in `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

Note that `sudo` and `su` are completely different programs. You can't change the behavior of `su` by changing the configuration of `sudo`.

Comment: Ok, I see. My question was just to ensure minimum security for su acces,even if this is not efective for sudo, like d33tah pointed.

Answer (score 0):

Root is not prompted password, Reason behind this is first line in `/etc/pam.d/su`.

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

I think some lines should be added before this to ask root to authenticate for particular user.